# Mule returns 500 instead of 400

Tags: mule, http-status

I am making a http call to a flow that will call an http outbound endpoint. The outbound endpoint returns a message with `http.status = 400`. Until the last moment when I am in my flow the headers will show that the `http.status` is in fact 400.

But Mule will return the message with `http.status = 500 Internal Server Error` instead.

I have found this solution, but it doesn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486259/3510748

```
<set-variable variableName="http.disable.status.code.exception.check"
          value="true" />
```

When I set this before my http outbound endpoint `http.status` will change to 200 which isn't correct either.

What do I need to do to receive the correct http.status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the HTTP headers as outbound properties, so you should be able to do something like

```
<set-property propertyName="http.status" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]"/>
```

after the outbound HTTP call to respond with the exact same status. You will also need the http.disable.status.code.exception.check to prevent an exception, unless you have some other type of exception handling.

Comment: Thanks Anton! Combining the `http.disable.status.code.exception.check` with adding the `http.status` as an `outboundproperty` did the trick!