# how to invoke other flow based success of one flow in mule

Tags: mule

```
   <flow name="flow1">
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/HealthInsurance/save" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
   </flow

   <flow name="flow2">
       <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8080/HealthInsurance/list" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" />
   </flow
```

I have above flow in mule. Flow1 successful response means invoke flow2,  otherwise  **any exception in flow1 means, no need to invoke flow2.** This is very important. Anybody have any idea about  my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using HTTP outbound in your **flow1**.. you can invoke the **flow2** when the http response **status** is **200** something like this for success :- `<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] == '200']">`

[Mule - unable to route message based on http.status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23651980/mule-unable-to-route-message-based-on-http-status)

.. and you can use exception strategy to log the exception

Comment: That's fine. but only success means invoke the other flow. exception comes means stop the flow2 .for that wat is the solution ??

Comment: So you can stop the flow in the exception block .. check this for stopping the flow using expression component :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387745/how-to-stop-a-mule-flow-from-running-after-startup

Comment: But if you stop the flow .. just remember you can't call it next time until you again start it using the same technique from your main flow

Comment: @muledevlepoer24 what do you mean by "stop the flow2" ?, with the above solution flow2 will not be invoked is'nt that enough ?